# How do I copy a structure?

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, free, memcpy

I have a problem where I have to copy a structure and add it to new memory then free the old memory. Then I have to increment to create space for new memory and add again. I thought I had the logic correct but I keep getting a segmentation fault. I can't figure out where I am going wrong.

Here is a copy of my structure:

```
struct childrensBook *book = (struct childrensBook *) malloc(sizeof(struct childrensBook));     //Structure of book #1

book->title = (char *)malloc(100);                  //allows memmory of 100 characters                                                  
book->author = (char *)malloc(100);             //allows memmory of 100 characters  
book->publisher = (char *)malloc(100);              //allows memmory of 100 characters  
book->copyright = 0;
book->price = 0;
```

Here is a copy of my add function:

```
int addRecord() 
{
    int headptr = 0;
    struct childrensBook *book = malloc(sizeof(struct   childrensBook));            //get book structure
    struct childrensBook *book1 = malloc(sizeof(struct childrensBook));         //create structure book1
    memcpy(book->title, "We're Going on a Bear Hunt", 26);                      //populate fields of book 
    memcpy(book->author, "Michael Rosen", 13);                                  //populate fields of book 
    memcpy(book->publisher, "Little Simon", 12);                                //populate fields of book 
    book->copyright = 1989;                                                 //populate fields of book 
    book->price = 7.99;                                                     //populate fields of book 
    memcpy(book1, book, sizeof *book1);                     //copy fields of book to book 1
    free(book);
}
```

And here is my call to function:

```
else if(x==4)
{
    addRecord();
    fprintf(stderr, "You have added the record: %s\n", book->title);
    free(book);
    moveptr++;   //here to incrememnt for new space. This is a globaal variable
}
```

Comment: Do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C. (Note that you are already inconsistenly casting/not casting in your code). And **always** check the result of functions which might encounter an error: `malloc` might return a _null pointer_!

Comment: Use `strncpy` to copy strings! And do not use magic numbers! And use normal assignment to copy a `struct`. `memcpy` inhibits type-checking.

Comment: At which line is there a segmentation fault? This is very important and very easy to diagnose, so you should do it in order to get good answers.

Answer (score 2):

I see multiple errors here:

- `free(book)` frees the dynamically allocated `struct book` but not its dynamically allocated fields (`book->title` and such things must be freed too)
- you are calling `memcpy` to `book->author` and other `char*` fields but these fields haven't been dynamically allocated, maybe you wanted to do `book->title = strdup("literal")`,
- `memcpy(book1, book, sizeof *book1)` has at least two errors: first you hare coping `sizeof *book1 bytes`, which is the size of a pointer, not the whole struct. Then you are copying fields which doesn't contain primitive types but pointers which would then share ownership between two books, you should copy each single dynamically allocated field.

Just to give some code to start with:

```
void free_book(struct book* b) {
  free(b->title);
  free(b->author);
  ...
  free(b);
}

struct* book dupe_book(struct book* source) {
  struct book* dest = malloc(sizeof(struct book));
  dest->price = source->price;
  dest->author = strdup(source->author);
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`memcpy` do not add null terminator. So either add `'\0'` after `memcpy` manually or increase number of byte in `memcpy` .

Do this -

```
memcpy(book->title, "We're Going on a Bear Hunt", 26); // or use strncpy so it will add null terminator          
memcpy(book->author, "Michael Rosen", 14);                                   
memcpy(book->publisher, "Little Simon", 13);
```

And because your `book->title` is not null terminated , therefore , `fprintf` with specifier `%s` gives seg fault.

And if you use fixed memory in `malloc`(i.e `100`) , why use it ? Declare  them as arrays -

```
book->title = (char *)malloc(100);          // in struct declare title as char title[100]             
book->author = (char *)malloc(100);         // similar with rest.     
book->publisher = (char *)malloc(100);
```

Then you won't have take tension to `free` it.

*Note* - If you use `malloc` then as also mentioned in comment , please don't cast result of `malloc`.

Comment: `strdup()` is a lot clearer and less error-prone than `malloc()` followed by `memcpy()` with magic numbers.

Comment: @AndrewHenle  It  clearly is , I just mentions cause of segmentation fault .

Comment: @AndrewHenle, true, but `strdup` is not standard.

Comment: @AndrewHenle If using fixed size then why not declare array as I mentioned . No need of `malloc`.

Comment: @AlterMann, `strdup()` is part of the IEEE Std 1003.1, 2004 Edition standard:  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strdup.html

Comment: @AndrewHenle  Its POSFIX not part of ISO C standard and  portability issues are also there.

Comment: @Andrew, POSIX is  a standard operating system interface, but not THE standard.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to copy over the null-terminators on your string literals:

You need to use `"Little Simon", 13` instead etc.: `"Little Simon"` is not as little as you think. It occupies 13 bytes, not 12.

Else your `fprintf` will overrun past your string, with disastrous results: a segmentation fault being one possibility.

Answer (score 0):

In your case the structure `struct childrensBook` contains pointers to strings. If your want deep copy of that object you need also copy internal strings.

However, since you are using constant lengths for all string fields it is possible to use all string elements as `char` arrays. In that case the entire content will be stored in one piece of memory:

```
struct childrensBook {
    char title[100];
    char author[100];
    char publisher[100];
    int copyright;
    int price;
}

/* the structure content may be written as follows */
strcpy(book->title, "We're Going on a Bear Hunt");

/* structure copy by direct assignment */
*book1 = *book;
```